# How to send data attribute to laravel controller (to store on database) using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm a beginner in Laravel, and I've created this code for practice to store order number changes from images into a database. But I store the value in an **attribute**. The case here is to set the order number of images, using "sortable" function jQuery.

I've tried some search around the internet, but mostly they using `<input type="hidden" name="someName" value="{{ here's the value }}"` to store the value of the new order number. I'm just curious is that any possibility to take data from an attribute.

Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>No.</th>
                                    <th>Image</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>Order Number</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <tbody class='sort-list'>
                                <?php $i=1; ?>

                                @foreach ($images as $image)

                                <tr class="dataArray" data-index="{{ $image->id }}" data-position="{{ $image->order_number }}">
                                    <input type="hidden"
                                    <th scope="row">
                                        <?php echo $i; ?>.
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
                                            <a href="{{ asset('cms/images/carousel/'.$image->url_img)}}" data-sub-html="Description">
                                                <img class="img-responsive thumbnail" style="margin-bottom: 0;" src="{{ asset('cms/images/carousel/'.$image->url_thumb)}}">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @if ($image->is_active == 1)
                                        <span class="label bg-green">Active</span>
                                        @else
                                        <span class="label bg-deep-orange">Inactive</span>
                                        @endif
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ $image->order_number }}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php $i++; ?>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

So I used data-index and data-position attribute to store to the database.

**This is my jQuery and Ajax:**

```
<script>
    $('.sort-list').sortable({
        axis: 'y',
        opacity: 0.7,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        update: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).children().each(function (index) {
                if ($(this).attr('data-position') != (index+1)) {
                    $(this).attr('data-position', (index+1)).addClass('updated');
                }
            });

            saveNewPositions();
        }
    });
    function saveNewPositions() {
        var positions = [];
        $('.updated').each(function () {
            positions.push([$(this).attr('data-index'), $(this).attr('data-position')]);
            $(this).removeClass('updated');
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('/admin/setCarouselOrder') }}",
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: {
                update: 1,
                positions: positions
            }, success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }
```

**If this is PHP Native**, I will use this code:

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
        foreach($_POST['positions'] as $position) {
           $index = $position[0];
           $newPosition = $position[1];

           $conn->query("UPDATE country SET position = '$newPosition' WHERE id='$index'");
        }

        exit('success');
    }
```

What I've done for trial on controller is this:

```
public function setCarouselOrder(Request $r) {
   $result = Carousel::find($r->id);

   $newNumber = $r->data-position;
   foreach($result as $data)
   {
       $data->order_number=$newNumber;
   }
}
```

For your information, I'm using 'model' to access my database called "Carousel".
My Route on laravel is:

`Route::get('/admin/setCarouselOrder', 'AdminController@setCarouselOrder')->name('/admin/setCarouselOrder')`

But I'm a bit confused on how to achieve that on laravel controller? Please help me find out how. Need a solution here.

Thank You so much

Comment: you are using `$_POST` method at server side and `GET` in ajax, so change in ajax and replace `method: 'GET',` by `method: 'POST',`

Comment: It's just example, I haven't change yet since my last trial. The method I used for "PHP native" is `POST`. But I have another trial on laravel to edit data via json is using `GET` method, and it works. Let me know how it's suppose to be.. Thank you

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#updates

Comment: I've added from what I've done on my controller, It's just not working. I've read that laravel doc, and I'm still confused to apply on my case. Thank you @SandeepSudhakaran , appreciate it

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below function in controller,

Note: please dont forget to add `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

```
 public function setCarouselOrder(Request $request){
    foreach($request->positions as $position) {
       $index = $position[0];
       $newPosition = $position[1];
       $affectedRows = Country::whereId($index)->update(['position' => $newPosition]);
    }
}
```

and your Route would like(use POST for form submission web services)

```
Route::post('/admin/setCarouselOrder', 'AdminController@setCarouselOrder')->name('admin.setCarouselOrder')
```

Assuming you have a `Country.php` model file
Hope this help. if you need more clarification, please let me know in comment

Comment: Works perfectly, Thank you so much.
So the answer I've been looking for is --> first attribute = $position[0] (and always be like that no matter I change the name). Second is $position[1] and so on..
is that correct?

Comment: Oh, by the way, I wonder is that would be any future error if I'm still using `GET` method. Because I forgot to change it, but it's still working properly..

Comment: can you please show `$request->all()`. then I can try to suggest better options.for now I dont know, how your request Formdata looks like

Comment: Taking by index is not recommendable. you can send `key:value` pair instead. is the `$index` is same for all positions?

Comment: It depends on your request type. if it is `GET` use `get` in your Route, if it is `POST` use `post`. you can also use `Route::match(['get', 'post'] ,'/admin/setCarouselOrder', 'AdminController@setCarouselOrder')`    and       `Route::any('/admin/setCarouselOrder', 'AdminController@setCarouselOrder')`

Comment: I did `dd(dd($request->all());` after `foreach`, but it throw an error `"Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"`..

Comment: use `print_r($request->all()); exit;` and then try. before foreach

Comment: $index = ID from each image.
using `print_r($request->all()); exit;` It turn out `Array ( )`.. So strange